# Relative paths allowed in libtool archive (.la) files?

Tags: autoconf, libtool

I am working on a (mostly C/C++) build environment that should be relocatable to a different folder location and system.

This actually already works, but when using libtool archive (.la) files there are warnings about those files being relocated. Basically this error can be ignored and everything builds fine.

So I was wondering if it's possible to have a relative path in `.la` files (for at least the `libdir` setting), or if there is some kind of built-in variable that can be used to refer to the path containing the `.la` file (similar to `${pcfiledir}` in pkg-config's `.pc` files).